# What are the April Fool's Day changes to GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Besides

> the [snow](https://www.pcgamer.com/rockstars-april-fools-prank-covers-gta-online-and-red-dead-online-in-a-blanket-of-snow/) (for 2020 April Fool's),

are there any other changes to the game for April Fool's Day?

Answer (score 1):

No. There were no other 2020 April Fool's jokes in GTA Online other than the sudden arrival of snow.